# Django handle multiple forms in class based view

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I have an update view for Updating user profile information. On that page I have added another form for password change that will work separately. Now, what I have done is that I have checked whether password changed form was submitted and taken the necessary action.
 What I want is that, if the user changed any data on the profile update form and submits the password change form with errors, then I should see the errors on the password form and the changed data on the user update form. How can that be done?

P.S: I was thinking that maybe I can handle this via AJAX request wherein I can send both form data by serializing them. But I want it to work without any AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

"*What I want is that, if the user changed any data on the profile update form and submits the password change form with errors, then I should see the errors on the password form and the changed data on the user update form.*"

One way of dealing with such problem is to send both forms together:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h2>Your User Update Form</h2>
    {% user_update_form %}

    <h2>Your Password Change Form</h2>
    {% password_change_form %}
</form>
```

and then in your view:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize both forms with prefixes
        user_update_form = UserUpdateForm(prefix='user_update')
        password_change_form = UserPasswordForm(prefix='password_change')
        return self._render_form(user_update_form, password_change_form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # read forms from POST
        user_update_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, prefix='user_update')
        password_change_form = UserPasswordForm(request.POST, prefix='password_change')

        # validate password form
        if password_change_form.is_valid():
            # do something
        else:
            # password form has errors, so return both forms
            return self._render_form(user_update_form , password_change_form)

    def _render_form(self, user_update_form, password_change_form ):
        context = {'user_update_form': user_update_form, 'password_change_form': password_change_form}
        return TemplateResponse(self.request, '**/your_template.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks but this is not a good option in the long run. Suppose if I use a third form somewhere else in the template where it can't be combined, then what?